# How to create Twilio Studio flow from java api for call forwarding

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I want to create a call forwarding flow in twilio from java api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is a [tutorial on call forwarding with Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/call-forwarding-java-spark) that might help you out.

Alternatively, here is a tutorial for setting up [call forwarding in Studio](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115016033048-Forward-Incoming-Calls-with-Twilio-Studio).

If you are looking to create the call forwarding flow itself in Studio using Java, the easiest thing to do is to create the flow in the Studio drag and drop editor, then [export the flow as JSON](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide#importing-and-exporting-flows). You can then [use that JSON in the API to create a flow](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/v2/flow#create-a-flow-resource). There is a [Java example for creating flows via the API here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/rest-api/v2/flow?code-sample=code-create-flow&code-language=Java&code-sdk-version=8.x).

Comment: This was very helpful, https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide#importing-and-exporting-flows. This link helped me solve my issue. thankyou.